# dplyr: Arrange not behaving as expected after group_by and summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

I must be missing something with how `group_by` levels in `dplyr` get peeled off. In the example below, I group by 2 columns, summarize values into a single variable, then sort by that new variable:

```
mtcars %>% group_by( cyl, gear ) %>% 
  summarize( hp_range = max(hp) - min(mpg)) %>% 
  arrange( desc(hp_range) )

# Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
# Groups: cyl [3]
#
#    cyl  gear  hp_range
#  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1     4     4  87.6
#2     4     5  87.0
#3     4     3  75.5
#4     6     5 155.3
#5     6     4 105.2
#6     6     3  91.9
#7     8     5 320.0
#8     8     3 234.6
```

Obviously this is not sorted by `hp_range` as intended. What am I missing?

EDIT: The example works as expected without the call to `desc` in arrange. Still unclear why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, just got to the bottom of this:

1. The call to `desc` had no effect, it was by chance that the example did not work without it
2. The key is that when you `group_by` multiple columns, it seems that results are automatically sorted by the Groups. In the example above it is sorted by `cyl`. To get the intended sort of the entire data table, you must first `ungroup` and then `arrange`

   ```
   mtcars %>% group_by( cyl, gear ) %>% 
      summarize( hp_range = max(hp) - min(mpg)) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      arrange( hp_range )
   ```

Comment: I just wanted to tell you that all your questions and answers so far on this site have been very good.  Good clear explanations along with reproducible examples.  So thanks!